# How to access Google Cloud SQL Proxy from App Engine from DotNet App

Tags: mysql, google-app-engine, .net-core, google-cloud-sql

How to access Google Cloud SQL Proxy from App Engine from DotNet Core App.

- I wrote a Web App using DotNet Core / ASP.NET
- I tested the app locally with My SQL and Google Cloud SQL Proxy
- I deployed the app to Google App Engine

**Question:**

Is there a copy of the Google SQL Proxy on the Flex / Custom VM where my app is deployed?

How to access it from .NET Core?

Comment: It doesn't seem to work even if you enable it in app.yaml config using `beta_settings`. In Google Cloud docs .NET is the only language for which they ask you to open Cloud SQL to all IPs and then connect from AppEngine using IP+SSL cert.